# SQL variable returning the same result multiple times

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a query with two select statements. I need the second select statement to return a result based on the first statement. However the results returned by the second select statement are just the last result of the first selected statement, repeated.

Here is my query:

```
Declare
    @Low numeric (13,0) = 50000,
    @High numeric (13,0) = 60000,
    @State varchar(2),
    @Place varchar(5),
    @Gid2 varchar(7);

SELECT
    @State = State, @Place = Place
FROM
    [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE
    (NOT(SUMLEV = '50')) AND (NOT(COUNTY = 0)) AND (NOT(PLACE = '99990')) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 > @Low) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 < @High)

Set
    @Gid2 = CONCAT((REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(@State)) + @State),(REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(@Place)) + @Place))

SELECT
    @Gid2 AS Gid2
From
    [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE
    (NOT(SUMLEV = '50')) AND (NOT(COUNTY = 0)) AND (NOT(PLACE = '99990')) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 > @Low) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 < @High)
```

If you run the first select statement alone there are 270 results. What I am trying to accomplish is to get 270 unique results from the second query, but what I am getting are the results from the last record in the first query, repeated 270 times.

Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you are trying to do

```
Declare
    @Low numeric (13,0) = 50000,
    @High numeric (13,0) = 60000,
    @Gid2 varchar(7);

SELECT
    CONCAT((REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(State)) + State),(REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(Place)) + Place)) Gid2
FROM
    [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE
    (NOT(SUMLEV = '50')) AND (NOT(COUNTY = 0)) AND (NOT(PLACE = '99990')) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 > @Low) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 < @High)
```

Comment: that is exactly that i am trying to accomplish. so i was going one step too far with the two select statements. i didn't think about trying to accomplish this in one step. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set
@Gid2 = CONCAT((REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(@State)) + @State),(REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(@Place)) + @Place))

SELECT
    @Gid2 AS Gid2
From
[SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE
(NOT(SUMLEV = '50')) AND (NOT(COUNTY = 0)) AND (NOT(PLACE = '99990')) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 > @Low) AND (ESTIMATESBASE2010 < @High)
```

that would just present the value of @Gid2 for any record returned from the query. try select * or select any column from that table

Comment: the purpose of the second query is to only return the value of '@Gid2. the problem is that it is only returning the last result from the first select statement. the first select statement, when run alone returns 270 unique records, so what i need is for my second select statement to return 270 unique values for '@Gid2.